# How do I parse through an infinite scrolling page (ex. Wallbase.cc/search/sky) with Python?

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, mechanize

Not sure if there's anything with Mechanize or BeautifulSoup that could help. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mechanize and Beautiful soup can't inteface with the javascript used for the infinite scroll.

Selenium can.

Additionally if you were to view the ajax requests when you use the infinite scroll you would see a post request to `http://wallbase.cc/search/160` with the request data:

```
query:sky
board:123
res_opt:eqeq
res:0x0
aspect:0
nsfw_sfw:1
nsfw_sketchy:0
nsfw_nsfw:0
thpp:32
orderby:relevance
orderby_opt:desc
```

160 corresponds to the image range so the request before it was `wallbase.cc/searc/128`.

Comment: So if I wanted to scrape the wallpapers and write each into a folder, how would I get past the javascript used for loading the infinite scroll to load the next page of wallpapers? Currently I can only grab the wallpapers all the way up until the javascript it loaded.